# How do I create a new thread(s) that draws to the screen in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, draw, paintcomponent, graphics2d

Right now I have a main game loop that constantly redraws the screen. Since I need to slow this thread down but continue to draw other items at a faster rate I need to make a new thread. The problem is I am not sure how to go about making a new thread that also draws to the screen  I know how to make a new thread, I am just stuck on how to implement the Graphics2D drawing in the new thread. For example I have the code below which is the typical starting point and then there is the draw method defined in the other class that directs what and when to draw. If I wanted to branch off and have another thread drawing and doing its own thing how do I do that?

Do I have to make a new class that creates an entirely new PaintComponent()?  Or would I simply create a new Graphics2D object so I can use different font colors and such? I guess what confuses me most is that I can't just call a different draw method because I still need to pass g2d as the argument. So it appears to me that I need to make the thread from within another method that already has the g2d object.

If this is confusing I do apologize as I am still a beginner to JAVA. If you need more information just let me know. Thank you in advance.

```
 public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g2d);



@Override

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

super.paintComponent(g2d);

draw(g2d);
}
```

Comment: I'm very far from being a gaming expert, but I think you should stick to a unique game loop that redraws things that must be redrawed at a fast rate at each iteration, and only draws things that should be drawn at a slow rate every N iterations.

Comment: That is certainly one way of going about things. If I understand what you are saying you suggest that I could use a counter and only have one loop go every so many counts. I think in this case though I really need to use multiple threads. It would be good for me to learn how to use them better anyway as more advanced games would pretty much require it. Thank you for your input. I will wait and see if anyone else some ideas as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, Swing is inherently single-threaded. This was once summarized in the "single thread rule"

> Once a Swing component has been realized, all code that might affect or depend on the state of that component should be executed in the event-dispatching thread.

(Unfortunately, the respective site did not survive the migration of Java from Sun to Oracle, but some information can be found here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html or when doing a websearch for "swing single thread rule")

In general, this applies also to *painting* : The `paintComponent` may only safely be called by the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). And it will be called "automatically". That is why this technique is called *"passive rendering"*: You overwrite the `paintComponent` method, expecting that it will be called by the EDT.

However, particularly for game development, you can use a technique called *"active rendering"*. In this case, painting is slightly more complicated and involves setting up an own `BufferStrategy`. The potential advantage is that *any* thread may perform rendering operations in this case, because you can obtain a `Graphics` object by calling `BufferStrategy#getDrawGraphics`.

Information can be found at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/rendering.html (while this refers to fullscreen rendering, similar concepts can be applied to active rendering in a window, but I'd recommend to consult further tutorials/resources that can be found with keywords like "swing active rendering").

Comment: Thanks Marco13. I will have to read up on that. Hopefully it is not terribly complicated. If it will allow me to have more freedom to draw in different threads then it might be worth the effort. At least now I have something to go on.